# Wordpress : How Do I get taxonomy name in taxonomy.php?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I am able to display the term of the taxonomy in the taxonomy page, but how do I get the taxonomy , or display the taxonomy on the page.

for example, when I have a taxonomy called "fruit" and I click on a fruit term called "lemons", How do I display both "lemons" and "fruit" on the taxonomy term page?

Just looking for the get term equivalent. Thx!

Answer (score 12):

A possible solution:

```
$taxonomy = get_queried_object();
echo  $taxonomy->name;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
get_query_var('taxonomy');
```

Just this should work.

Answer (score 6):

For my taste is overly complicated, but here it goes:

```
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
echo $term->name;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you check `$wp_query->get_queried_object()` on a taxonomy page, this will contain the term object, which has a reference to the taxonomy identifier (in my example it's `replymc_people`). Pass this to `get_taxonomy`, and you get the full taxonomy object.

```
object(stdClass)[325]
  public 'term_id' => string '113' (length=3)
  public 'name' => string 'Jef Staes' (length=9)
  public 'slug' => string 'jef-staes' (length=9)
  public 'term_group' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'term_taxonomy_id' => string '107' (length=3)
  public 'taxonomy' => string 'replymc_people' (length=14)
  public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
  public 'count' => string '3' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a solved problem but here's another way to get the taxonomy name which I think is clean. For those finding this just now as I did. I like to promote awareness of global variables in wordpress.

```
$tax_term = $wp_query->query_vars['tax_name'];
```

Comment: Just to help anyone else looking, yes this does give 'lemons' (using the OP's example), but to get 'fruit' you can use $wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy']

Answer (score 3):

I know this is answered, but for those who might wind up on this page when searching...

```
global $taxonomy,$term;
```

$taxonomy will now contain your taxonomy name ('fruit' from the OP's example) and your taxonomy term name ('lemon' from OP's example).

Answer (score 2):

You can get specific term / taxonomy data like name, description etc on taxonomy.php

```
<?php 
$termid = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$term = get_term( $termid, 'taxonomy-name' );
echo $term->name.'<br>';
echo $term->description;
?>
```

Comment: Downvoting as `$taxonomy = get_queried_object();` already returns the $term you're looking for, no need to execute that extra query by ID. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might step this way  (I did) so...

```
$tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$tax_term = $tax->name;
$tax = get_taxonomy($tax->taxonomy);
$taxonomy =  $tax->label;
echo "$tax_term are $taxonomy";
```

returns "Lemons are Fruit".

I'd love to know a one liner for this but I don't think there is one, you need parts of two objects.

Answer (score 0):

As of Wordpress version `3.1.0` for `single_term_title()` and Wordpress version `4.9.2` for `term_description()`, both can be used to display the terms **name** and **description**. Here is an example.

```
<hgroup>
<h1><?php single_term_title(); ?></h1>
<h2><?= term_description(); ?></h2>
</hgroup>
```

Alternatively you can use `get_the_archive_title()` to display the taxonomy name and curren associated term. A typical result would be: `Taxonomy: Term`.

---

### More

- `single_term_title()` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_term_title/
- `term_description()` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_description/
- `get_the_archive_title()` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/